# The unicoins made problem in stackoverflow website

Tags: discussion, unicoins

The link of unicoins from footer and sidebar is deleted from stackoverflow (can't undo changes) , and now i can't UPvote or Downvote anything.

What is the problem and what can i do now ?

Comment: Sounds like some JavaScript problem. What browser are you using? Are there any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @balpha You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

There was a javascript problem in website and fixed by clearing browser cache .

Happy with Unicoins :D

Comment: Always caching...